# Bootstrap inputs align in CSS Box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a problem with my css box , i created jsfiddle

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uvg6dtxa/9/)

- the inputs need to be aligned vertically and horizontally
- I need to make a responsive **CSS box** to control the div

Here my CSS:

```
 .CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginTop,
 .CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderTop,
 .CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingTop {
    left: 45%;
    top: 12px;
 }

 .CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginRight,
 .CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderRight,
 .CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingRight {
    top: 50%;
    right: 8px;
 }

 .CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginBottom,
 .CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderBottom,
 .CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingBottom {
    left: 46%;
    bottom: 6px;
 }

 .CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginLeft,
 .CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderLeft,
 .CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingLeft {
    top: 46%;
    left: 8px;
 }
```

Comment: it is happening due to different values of `top` and `left`

Comment: @amit , yes it is happening due to different values of top and left  :D

Comment: better divided a row into 7 column and proceed..

Comment: @MohamedSamy it's due to you are providing the all 3 main div's height as hard coded that and you need to set left right bottom top with respect to divide by 3 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with `top, right, bottom, left` values is not enough. You should give negative `margin` and change the height of all the boxes to get this effect.

If width of the input box is `30px` and height is `25px` you should give negative margin `= width(or)height/2` respective it.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/xecps98v/1/

Comment: Thanks Man , you save me life

Answer (score 1):

If you correct the height of the various containers so that the height and margins add up correctly to the parent's height you could use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to move each `<input>` into the correct position. Please note I had to change the `.MargingBox` to use the default [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) of `content-box;` otherwise the calculated width and height included the `1px` margin which shifted the outer left and right inputs up by `1px`.

```css
.CssBox .MargingBox {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed #CCC;
    height: 250px;
}
.CssBox .BorderBox {
    position: relative;
    margin: 44px;
    height:162px;
    background-color: #E3E7ED;
}
.CssBox .PaddingBox {
    position:relative;
    top:44px;
    margin: 44px;
    height:74px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
.CssBox input {
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginTop, .CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderTop, .CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingTop {
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
    top: 12px;
}
.CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginRight, .CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderRight, .CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingRight {
    top: calc(50% - 12.5px);
    right: 8px;
}
.CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginBottom, .CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderBottom, .CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingBottom {
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
    bottom: 6px;
}
.CssBox .MargingBox input#MarginLeft, .CssBox .BorderBox input#BorderLeft, .CssBox .PaddingBox input#PaddingLeft {
    top: calc(50% - 12.5px);
    left: 8px;
}
.CssBox .MargingBox {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal-body container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-8 CssBox">
            <div class="MargingBox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control margin_part" id="MarginTop" placeholder="-">
                <input type="text" class="form-control margin_part" id="MarginRight" placeholder="-">
                <input type="text" class="form-control margin_part" id="MarginBottom" placeholder="-">
                <input type="text" class="form-control margin_part" id="MarginLeft" placeholder="-">
                <div class="BorderBox">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control .padding_part" id="BorderTop" placeholder="-">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control .padding_part" id="BorderRight" placeholder="-">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control .padding_part" id="BorderBottom" placeholder="-">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control .padding_part" id="BorderLeft" placeholder="-">
                    <div class="PaddingBox row-fluid">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingTop" placeholder="-">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingRight" placeholder="-">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingBottom" placeholder="-">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PaddingLeft" placeholder="-">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you dont use Bootstraps CSS with this and use your own using Flex/Flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) CSS as this will have a better outcome. Also use media queries so the box shows correctly on smaller displays/resizing